# Could not initialize class with mapGroupsWithState

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm trying to create a spark structured streaming application with arbitrary state, when I add groupByKey and mapGroupWithState it gives me an error after starting the first task.

```
  .groupByKey(_.user_id)
  .mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.NoTimeout)(sessionState.updateAcrossEvents)
```

Error:
Lost task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5, node, executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.test.Run$

Run is the main class which contains the main method.

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

PS: if i write directly to console without groupByKey and mapGroupsWithState it works fine.

Comment: Where u able to solve this issue?